# Describing mappings using dynamics of time-dependent ODE-flows

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, initial-value-problems

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$. When is it possible to find some $g\in C^1([0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n)$, uniformly Lipschitz continuous w.r.t the second argument, such that if $u_{x_0}$ is the solution of the IVP
$$ \dot{x}(t) = g(t,x(t)),\quad x(0) = x_0,$$
we have $f = x_0\mapsto u_{x_0}(1)$? I.e., what do we need from $f$ for it to be describable by the (time-dependent) flow given by an ODE? How can find that ODE?

I figured these might be questions answered in the analysis of dynamical systems (or not because of the time-dependency?); can somebody give a brief answer or direction on where to go looking?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit: The question is on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/317480/final-time-maps-of-ivps-approximating-functions-x-subseteq-mathbbrn-to-math) now.

Comment: For autonomous vector fields this is a nontrivial problem. In the nonautonomous case it should be simpler (but I don't know how much). At any rate, neither Google nor MR search give any definite results. Perhaps you could try, if there are no responses here, asking at Math.Overflow?

Comment: @user539887 Thank you for your comment. I will follow your advice! And perhaps put a bounty, too.

Answer (score 2):

First, of course if you are looking for an autonomous differential equation this is impossible (think of $f(x)=-\frac 12 x$, clearly there is no one dimensional system $\dot x=g(x)$ that would correspond to it). If, however, you allow an ODE on a manifold then the inverse problem always can be solved. It is called a *suspension* system. You can find some general remarks about such systems in Section 1.5.1 of Kuznetsov's book Applied bifurcation theory. In Chapter 9 of the same book the author constructs explicit systems of ODEs approximating certain maps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was a big step in the right direction. However, his general result applies to any function and relies on a special choice of topology on $[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}^n$ that I can't really work with. The further chapters seem to be interested in local approximation... I won't accept your answer just yet.

Comment: @Ramen You are right about the topology: Take $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x)=-x$. If $f$ could be obtained as a time-one map of some nonautonomous ODE then it would be isotopic to identity, which it is not (as it reverses orientation).